# Mocking a function with a certain argument in Python

Tags: python, mocking

I have a module a.py:

```
def add(x, y):
    return x + y

def do_math(x):

    sum1 = add(x, 1)
    sum2 = add(x, 2)
    sum3 = add(x, 3)

    return sum1 + sum2 + sum3
```

Running the do_math function in a test results in the following:

```
print a.do_math(1)
9
```

I want to mock the add function when y is 2.  However, the following results in an infinite loop:

```
def mock_add(*args, **kwargs):
    x = args[0]
    y = args[1]
    if y == 2:
        return 4
    else:
        a.add(x, y)

with patch('a.add', side_effect=mock_add):
    a.do_math(1)
```

Here is a portion of my error message:

```
  File "E:\somepath\mock-1.3.0\mock\mock.py", line 1062, in __call__
    return _mock_self._mock_call(*args, **kwargs)
  File "E:\somepath\mock-1.3.0\mock\mock.py", line 1067, in _mock_call
    self.called = True
RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object
```

I should have known better.  I was already mocking add with mock_add.  Any ideas on how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Why not just save the function before the call?

```
from mock.mock import patch
import a

original = a.add
def mock_add(*args, **kwargs):
    x = args[0]
    y = args[1]
    if y == 2:
        return 4
    else:
        return original(x, y)

with patch('a.add', side_effect=mock_add):
    a.do_math(1)
```

If you want to keep the object orientated nature, you can store all of these inside a MagicMock object, but I think this answers your question.